# EclipseLink MOXy exception due to package structure

Tags: java, jaxb, eclipselink, package, moxy

I have this bindings file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xml-bindings
xmlns="http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/persistence/oxm"
package-name="com">
<java-types>
    <java-type name="com.test.Root">
        <xml-root-element name="root"/>
        <java-attributes>
            <xml-element java-attribute="element" xml-path="element" type="com.Element"/>
        </java-attributes>
    </java-type>
    <java-type name="com.Element"></java-type>
</java-types>
```

The package structure and the class location are as can be read off this bindings file. 
When I unmarshall I get the following exception. Can somebody tell me why and how I can solve the problem? I don't want to change my package structure.

```
JAXBException: The java-type with package [com.test] is not allowed in the bindings file keyed on package [com].
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have one binding file per package.  BTW when you specify the package name in the `xml-bindings` element you don't need to fully qualify the name on the `java-type` element.

Comment: Where do I place the bindings file then and how do I reference them? So far I give a properties map to JAXBFactory when I instantiate JAXBContext. But I don't see how I can specify multiple binding files?

Comment: Found how to do it: http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/MOXy/MultipleBindingsFiles Thanks!